# Instead of substring() function what can I use in matlab R2016b

Tags: matlab, substring

I want to implement the following statement in Matlab R2016b

```
file_a = substring(char(file_a), 0, findstr(char(file_a), '_')-2);
```

Here, file_a having 101_1 to 101_8, 102_1 to 102_8 and so on.

substring() is not evaluated in the R2016b release.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your expected result?

```
file_a = '101_1'
file_a = extractAfter(file_a,strfind(file_a,'_')-2)
```

this code produces a `file_a` of `'1_1'`.

```
file_a = '101_1'
file_a = extractBefore(file_a,strfind(file_a,'_')-1)
```

this code produces a `file_a` of `'10'`

```
file_a = '101_1'
file_a = extractBetween(file_a,strfind(file_a,'_')-1,strfind(file_a,'_'))
```

this code produces a `file_a` of `'1_'`